# Got error like this (Php & mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, database, web, sql-function

This is my sql function

```
CREATE FUNCTION returnPrice(price int,member int)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
RETURN(price*member);
END;
```

And this is my php code

```
$res1= "CALL returnPrice('$cost','$team_member')";
$rs1 = mysqli_query($con,$res1);
$row1= mysqli_fetch_array($rs1);
```

And then i got error like

> 'Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, boolean given in' in $row1... line

I don't know what is wrong. pls help

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0):

Acording to [mysqli.query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

> Returns FALSE on failure.

To check the reason of the failure you might try the following

```
$res1= "CALL returnPrice('$cost','$team_member')";
$rs1 = mysqli_query($con,$res1);
if ($rs1 === false) {
   printf("Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
   die();
}
$row1= mysqli_fetch_array($rs1);
```